# in java How to use arithmatic statements like sum or subtract on the Strings that have numbers and + and - and space char in it?

Tags: java, arrays, string, discrete-mathematics

i have a string that has sum numbers and space and som '+'and'-' characters  between them .i want to now How can summand and subtract them.!!
like 
String s="25+14-13+225-16";
and i want to output to be =235

Comment: Please show us this `String` and your effort on how to resolve the problem... You will have to split the `String` and handle the parts separately.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the code you're having problems with

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException {
    ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    String foo = "40+2";
    System.out.println(engine.eval(foo));
    } 
}
```